# Refactoring a field in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When i rename a variable in eclipse using Ctrl+1 it doesnt rename the getter/setter methods.  Is there any way to rename the methods as well.

Comment: @Dinup kandel This will not rename the getters/setters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Alt+Shift+R` on the required field. In the dialog that appears select 'Open Rename Dialog' and check the corresponding checkboxes

Comment: The checkbox for change getter/settr is not enabled

Comment: Do you have getters/setters for the field in question already in place?

Answer (score 9):

Rename the field using *Refactor > Rename* and choose "open rename dialog" in the tooltip. Or, simpler, press Ctrl+R twice.

In the rename dialog you can then choose to rename the getter and the setter of the field as well.

The setting you apply there is persistent, so after checking *Rename getter* and *Rename setter*, the next inline-rename will honor the setting as well and rename the getters and setters.

[image: Rename dialog in Eclipse 3.7]

Comment: Even if pankar already answered the same: +1 for the hint of pressing Ctrl+R twice.

Comment: The checkbox for rename getter/settr is not enabled

Comment: @mangalashenoy then you don't have getters or setters that match the naming convention (get/is/set + title cased field name). This could be because you already renamed the field. Use a 2-step process then: rename the field to match the property accessor names, then rename it again.

Answer (score 5):

`Select Field - > right click - > Refactor-> encapsulate field`.